# I need to get the image from an ImageView using this method, but with an unspecified drawable from the camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, bitmapfactory

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.awesome);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
imageview.buildDrawingCache (true);
   Bitmap bitmap = imageview.getDrawingCache (true);
```